# Codeigniter 3.0.0 session driver FILES is not writing session to a cache file at the realhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

It's working fine at the localhost, but at the real host session does not create a session cache file to a folder!

I set permissions to `0700` and tried `0777`. Tried copy files over and over again from local to real host. Nothing seems to be helping.

Where should I look?

Comment: i had something simular not so long ago, turned out i wasnt paying enough attention.... it had nothing to do with permissions. If i remember correctly my PHP on the server was missing the php55w-gd module that i needed to edit pictures and write to a folder on the server..... you might wanna check out if any errors are being print in your error log, if your permissions are 777 and you have upload issues..... it must be something else then permission issues

Comment: appreciate your reply jcoppens! i have same CI framework in a nested folder for admin part and inside this folder session works fine! it seems like in a root directory CI framework SESSION is not working ....

Comment: Set the appropriate *sess_save_path* for the server environment. And while you're changing stuff, you should also update your CI version to the latest one.